# How can I delete all unordered lines from a text file?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

**Overview**

Consider an ordered list interspersed with unordered elements, e.g.:

```
Alligator
Ant
Falcon <--
Baboon
Badger    
Armadillo <--
Caiman
Cat
```

How can this list be processed so that all unordered elements are deleted? E.g.:

```
Alligator
Ant
Baboon
Badger    
Caiman
Cat
```

**Some more information**

The unordered elements are always singular, the ordered elements come in groups of at least 2 lines. The general pattern would be:

```
ordered
ordered
ordered
unordered <--
ordered
ordered
unordered <--
ordered
ordered
```

The unordered elements can be both lower...

```
A
B
F <---
D
E
```

...and higher than the following ordered element:

```
A
C
B <---
D
E
```

To make matters even more difficult: The elements can be both upper- and lowercase and contain diacritics (e.g.: ä,ö,à).

---

Is there any way to accomplish this with bash?

Comment: Apparently, from the example you give, what you actually do is reading the list from bottom to top and removing a word if it's not -- in the alphabetical order -- lower than the previous one (i.e. the word on the line below). Is that actually what you are trying to do or did I get it wrong ?

Comment: It is not trivial to determine which lines are the ones to be deleted. `animal, baboon, yo-yo, zoo` could be the ordered lines, the others to be deleted. You can easily detect the points where ordering stops but you do not easily know whether the former or the later line is the problem. You need an unambiguous algorithm for that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging You are right, I didn't consider this when constructing the example. The real case might be a bit easier to solve: It's always one unordered line at a time, so you would have a long list of ordered items (o) interspersed by very few single unordered items (u), e.g.: o-o-o-o-o-o-u-o-o-o-o-o-u-o-o-u. Would this make the problem more feasible to solve with command line tools?

Comment: No, you will always need to script something but that should be possible. Can you show us a better example?

Comment: If what you want is "remove as few lines as possible to have all the file ordered", then no, there is no easy way to do it. Command-line tools such as sed reads your file just once. You  need a multi pass algorithm in your case.

Comment: @terdon updated the question with better examples and more information. lgeorget: (concerning your first comment) No, that wouldn't work becase the unordered lines can be both higher and lower than the next element (see updated description).

Comment: How do you decise it's B and not C that is out of order in your last example?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The decision would have to be made based on the group size. In this scenario ordered elements always come in groups of at least 2. `C`could only be the odd one out if there was an element before A.

Comment: Some of the ideas here might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641879/best-way-to-find-a-number-in-an-array-thats-out-of-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works if the last line is OK:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}; NR==1 {lastline=$0; next;}; {if($0>lastline) {print lastline; '\
'lastline2=lastline; lastline=$0;} else if ($0>lastline2) lastline=$0; }; '\
'END {print lastline;}' file1.txt
```

**old version** (with bugs, for comparison)

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}; NR==1 {lastline=$0; next;}; '\
'{if($0>lastline) print lastline; lastline=$0;}; END {print lastline;}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works great if all elements are lowercase and don't use any special diacritics (as shown in the examples). Unfortunately the phrases I am working with are both upper/lowercase and contain diacritics. [This seems to mess the results up](http://pastebin.com/E5g86YHL). Would it be possible to modify your script to work under these circumstances?

Comment: @Glutanimate I am not familiar with `awk`'s internationalization. I believed this works automatically. What is your locale? If this is not easily possible with `awk` then you may use Graeme's locale-aware shell solution instead.

Comment: Ah, nervmind. The issue with diacritics was my fault. The first element in the example I linked to ("äpple") should have come after "apple". That's how diacritics are generally sorted in my locale. The issue with different cases remains, though. The items in my list are only sorted alphabetically and without regard to their capitalization. Would it be possible to make awk's sorting case insensitive as well?

Comment: @Glutanimate I have made a change. Check whether the case problem is solved now.

Comment: That turns b c a d e into b a d e

Comment: Stephane is right. I am afraid I didn't look at the results thoroughly enough. This script works great if the unordered element in the list is lexicographically lower than the following ordered element (e.g.: j k **z** l m). OTOH, if the unordered element is lexicographically higher (e.g. e f g **a** h i)  we see the behaviour Stephane pointed out.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas And it's not even a coding error, it's an algorithm error...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Next try.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I think this is it (well, almost): ✔ Filters out all unordered elements (in both directions); ✔ is case insensitive (after a small tweak). I am still having some trouble with diacritics, though. `awk`just doesn't seem to want to follow canon in how the letters are sorted. E.g.: `sort` will sort `b c d a ä` to `a ä b c d` but if given the latter as an input your snippet removes `a`. I can only assume that awk isn't registering the locale. It's strange though, because everything else does.

Answer (score 4):

Shell solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=
before=
read -r current

while read -r after
do
  [[ "$before" < "$current" || "$before" = "$current"  ]] &&
    [[ "$current" < "$after" || "$current" = "$after"  ]] &&
    printf '%s\n' "$current" &&
    before="$current"

  current="$after"
done

[[ "$before" < "$current" || "$before" = "$current"  ]] &&
  printf '%s\n' "$current"
```

Usage: `./script <input_file`

Note that with `bash` you can use `[[..]]` comparisons for the lexical comparisons to be locale dependent and less naive (should work with ä,ö,à etc).

With reference to Stephane's point about how to decide for the last example in the question, this gives preference to the later occurrence. So it will actually remove `C`.

Comment: @Grame: Thank you for this script. It works great with different cases and also performs well for different locales and their diacritics. However, it seems to suffer from the same [sorting issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117296/how-can-i-delete-all-unordered-lines-from-a-text-file#comment182912_117304) as Hauke's awk snippet. E.g: e f g **a** h i is truncated to e f h i when it should be e f g h i.

Comment: @Glutanimate, I thought this was something relatively trivial to do, its not. You really have to come up with a good algorithm here, which unless you already know approaches to the problem, is going to take an afternoon to do properly. Also as Stephane says, this kind of stuff isn't really suited for shell scripting. IMO though it is fine for light use. You are probably best asking something more abstract on SO or Programmers. I would be interested to know if there is a simple way to do this though!

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, don't know if you will still get notifications for this, but what was the problem with `-o`?